# Writing on old handcarved stone teapot

Tags: translation

Looking for meaning or interpretation [image]of this carving on teapot.

Comment: Sorry, can't read one character on it. The photo was taken too close and the contrast could use some increasing.

Comment: It just says 乾隆年制